# How can I ensure that user registration data is stored in both the 'Register' and 'Login' tables in my database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, authentication

Why is the user registration data only being stored in the 'Register' table and not in the 'Login' table in my Django application with MySQL? How can I modify my code to ensure that the registration data is stored in both tables when a user registers? I have separate tables for registration and login, where the 'Register' table contains columns such as 'Ent_ID', 'Username', 'Email_ID', and 'Password', and the 'Login' table contains columns such as 'Login_ID', 'Ent_ID' (foreign key referencing 'Register' table), 'Email_ID', and 'Password'. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have created two tables in my Django application, 'Register' and 'Login', for user registration and login functionality respectively. The 'Register' table has columns like 'Ent_ID', 'Username', 'Email_ID', and 'Password', while the 'Login' table has columns like 'Login_ID', 'Ent_ID' (foreign key referencing 'Register' table), 'Email_ID', and 'Password'.

When a user registers, I expected their registration data to be stored in both the 'Register' and 'Login' tables. However, only the data is being stored in the 'Register' table and not in the 'Login' table. As a result, I am unable to perform login functionality using the registered credentials.

I have reviewed my code and made sure that the necessary relationships and foreign key constraints are set up correctly. However, I am still facing this issue. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to ensure that the registration data is stored in both tables when a user registers. Thank you!

Comment: How can we provide _"any insights"_ when you have not included any code? Why are you duplicating data between these two tables?

Comment: Is "register" some lingo in Django?

Comment: When you have two table that share the same info, consider having a third table that holds the common info.  Then us `JOIN` to connect the tables when reading.